# How to loop through an array and search attribute for a substring

Tags: ruby, search, substring

I need to loop through an array of objects Ads and find the ones who's attribute :name contains a substring of params[string_search]

Comment: You need a jQuery plugin for that

Comment: You must add a tag to your question representing the technologies that you are using so that we all can figure out what is the context of the question.

Comment: What have you written? Show us sample code of your work. It's a lot easier for us to fix what you've written, than to shoot in the dark guessing what you might have done.

Answer (score 4):

let ary be the array of Ads object. (hope you are using ruby)

```
ary.find{|obj| !obj.name.match(/#{params[string_search]}/).nil?}
```

use 'select' instead of 'find' to select all such objects

Comment: Yes I'm using ruby. I will try using this and see if it works

Comment: Hope this "params[string_search]" is "params[:string_search]", dont miss the colon

Answer (score 1):

this may work for you:

```
ads = Ads.select do |ad|
   ad.respond_to?(:name) && ad.name =~ /#{params[:string_search]}/
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Ruby, because of the symbol `:name`
This should put you in the right direction, you have an array of objects and are looking for the sting "ool" in the :name attribute.

```
a = [{:name => 'no'},{:name => 'pool'}, {:name => 'cool'}]
a.find_all{|elem| elem[:name].index "ool"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#assumes your array of objects is called 'foo'
foo.select{|o| o.name =~ /#{params[:string_search]}/}
```